# Pass an Array from Javascript via UIWebView in Swift

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, swift2

I have to use `UIWebView` in my project and I seem that I got a problem.

Well I have html as below.

```
<html>
<a onclick="myFunction(1)">element1</a>
<a onclick="myFunction(2)">element1</a>
<a onclick="myFunction(3)">element1</a>
</html>
```

When I click to the a href link I have to execute my javascript code

```
<script>
var arr = [];
function myFunction(number) {
    arr.push(number);
}
</script>
```

now how I can pass an `Array` to `UIViewController`?

and how I know in swift if I call `myFunction()` from `UIWebView`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You basically want to use Javascript to funnel some information over to Swift it seems. Why not make a request to the server for the JSON information, which you can then parse with Swift?

Comment: let's say JSON , how could i tell swift if he click on myFunction to execute an function within swift

Comment: https://tetontech.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/swift-to-javascript-and-javascript-to-swift-a-round-trip/ check this. It seems it is possible with `WKWebView`

Comment: What platform, iOS or OS X?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `WKWebView`, available since OS X 10.10 or iOS 8 to do the job. In Xcode 9 and later, you can add the `WkWebView` directly to Interface Builder and connect the `IBOutlet`. For earlier versions of Xcode, you must do so programmatically. For full compatibility, the code below shows how to add the `WKWebView` programmatically.

Make your view controller conform to the `WKScriptMessageHandler` protocol and add the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // myAction is the pipe name Javascript uses to post messages
        // to your app. You can define more than 1 pipe.
        let controller = WKUserContentController()
        controller.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "myAction")

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = controller

        // Add the WKWebView to the view
        let frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200)
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: config)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

        // Load your HTML file
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("mydoc", withExtension: "html")!
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessToURL: url)

        // Pass reference to the view controller
        self.webView = webView
    }

    // Handle the message posted by Javascript
    func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if let arr = message.body as? [Int] {
            print(arr)
        }
    }
}
```

And the HTML + Javascript:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Hello world</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var arr = [];

        function myFunction(number) {
            arr.push(number);

            // Send a message to your app on the myAction pipe
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.myAction.postMessage(arr);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction(1)">element1</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction(2)">element2</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction(3)">element3</a>
    </body>
</html>
```